# My app not working more than once

Tags: android

I am just fallowing a tutuorial on youtube the problem is that the code works just once .Next time when i try to exacute nothing happens The funny thing is that if i  create another app and copy and paste the code everything  seems ok But I cant still  work  second time until create and past the code another app .This process continues.

```
Boolean isFirst=getSharedPreferences("PREFER", MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean("isfirstrun", true);

        if(isFirst){

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "FIRST", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    getSharedPreferences("PREFER", MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putBoolean("isfirstrun",false).commit();

                }
```

Comment: Note, use `boolean` not `Boolean` here. If you don't know the difference yet it'll be interesting google for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the only thing your app supposed to do is show the Toast, then it is behaving as one would expect. Essentially, what your code is saying is "Only show a message if this is the first time this has run. Otherwise, do nothing." The reason it works when you create a new app is because the freshly installed app has a new Shared Preferences file, one that doesn't have the `isfirstrun` flag set.

To test, add another Toast after the `if-block`, and run it again. For example:

```
Boolean isFirst=getSharedPreferences("PREFER", MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean("isfirstrun", true);

if(isFirst){
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "FIRST", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    getSharedPreferences("PREFER", MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putBoolean("isfirstrun",false).commit();
}

Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "I'M REALLY RUNNING! HONEST!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```